# How do I brute-force a WPA-2 wifi with Aircrack-ng in Kali Linux?

Tags: penetration-test, brute-force, wpa2, aircrack-ng

What I basically want to do is, perform a test on my Wi-Fi and brute force it instead of a dictionary attack. I googled, and all of them showed me examples of dictionary attack and no bruteforcing.

My password is somewhat like this- `aXb2@abc`.

I know this can take a lot of time, but since it's my home I can let my computer do the work. Also, is there a better option than bruteforcing this type of passwords?
I am using Kali Linux 2. Thanks.

Comment: You could try to exploit WPS with reaver. That would take much less time than bruteforcing, which could literally take thousands of years.

Answer (score 0):

Use pyrit instead, it takes a few moments to get used to. It can distribute cracking over the network and utilize GPUs. Never had any luck with ocl-hashcat, but my GPU is worthless anyway. If you have a good one, it's worth looking into. On a weak i5 I get 1300 c/s with aircrack-ng and 1850 c/s with pyrit. It is still far too low of course, you need at least 50-100k c/s to get anywhere. If you prefer, there are numerous good online wpa-crackers. The one I used (years ago, no link) cost 5USD. Wordlists abound, google: 'intitle:"index of" wordlists rockyou pr0n twitter'. Read about common human pw schemes, like CCCCCCNNN, where C denotes alphabetic and N denotes numeric. Hashcat uses this masking pattern for bruteforce baboonery.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write RTFM first, but then I found the answer by accident ;-) You can specify

```
-w -
```

as parameter to aircrack-ng and then it will read the passwords from stdin.
There are lots of tools that help you generating passwords based on rules. Then you just pipe them into aircrack-ng, for instance:

```
crunch 4 5 0123456789 2> /dev/null | aircrack-ng [..options..] -w -
```

for brute forcing all passwords which consist of digits and are 4 or 5 characters long.